# Setting up uniform distribution over non-rectangular support

Tags: probability-or-statistics

$X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed over the triangle $T$ in the first quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$, so that

$$T=\{(x,y)\mid0\le x\le1,0\le y\le1-x\}$$

The joint PDF is then

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}2&\text{for }(x,y)\in T\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I'm asked to find various moments, covariance, correlation, etc. which are all easy to find by hand, but I'd like to check my results in *Mathematica*. **Are there built-in symbols that can handle this sort of distribution?**

The documentation for `UniformDistribution` suggests the support must be a rectangle. Trying to insert `1 - x` as the upper bound on `y` gives an incorrect, non-uniform PDF:

```
PDF[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1 - x}}], {x, y}]
(* Piecewise[{{(1 - x)^(-1), x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 1 - x >= 0 && 1 - x - y >= 0}}, 0] *)
```

i.e.

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac1{1-x}&\text{for }(x,y)\in T\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I know I can define my own PDF `f`,

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{2, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 - x}}]
```

and compute moments and co. by integrating `f` accordingly. But is there a way to set up a distribution `dist` so that I can check my work with `Expectation` or `Moment` etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Triangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Triangle.html) as a [region](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html). I use [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) here purely for visualization. It can be omitted.

```
reg = Region@Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

As Roman said, you can apply [`RegionMoment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMoment.html) to it:

```
RegionMoment[reg, {1, 0}]
(* 1/6 *)

RegionMoment[reg, {1, 0}]/RegionMoment[reg, {0, 0}]
(* 1/3 *)
```

For more complicated things, you can evaluate any integral over the region:

```
Integrate[Indexed[x, 1], x \[Element] reg]
(* 1/6 *)
```

For numerical verification, you can use [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html).

```
Moment[RandomPoint[reg, 10000], 1]
(* {0.332256, 0.335306} *)
```

Comment: Good point! In fact, you don't even need the `Region` in there: `RegionMoment[Triangle[{ ... }], {1, 0}]` works as well. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

A Dirichlet distribution with parameters $(1,1,1)$ will represent a uniform distribution over exactly the triangle you seek:

```
ListPlot[
  RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], 10000],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: scatter plot of points obtained from that distribution]

You can then obtain expectations, moments, etc using the usual statistical machinery in MMA. So for instance, to reproduce the results shown in [Roman's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211663/27951),

$E(X)$:

```
Moment[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], {1, 0}]     (* Out: 1/3  *)
```

$E(Y^2)$:

```
Moment[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], {0, 2}]     (* Out: 1/6  *)
```

$E(XY)$:

```
Moment[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], {1, 1}]     (* Out: 1/12 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

After some further investigation, it appears I can do what I want by using

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[2 Boole[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 - x], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Then e.g. $E[X]$, $E[Y^2]$, and $E[XY]$ are given respectively by

```
Moment[dist, {1, 0}]
(* 1/3 *)

Moment[dist, {0, 2}]
(* 1/6 *)

Moment[dist, {1, 1}]
(* 1/12 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define an implicit region

```
J = ImplicitRegion[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 1 - x >= 0 && 1 - x - y >= 0, {x, y}];
```

and then calculate its moments with [`RegionMoment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMoment.html).

The area is $1/2$, not $2$ as you had found:

```
RegionMoment[J, {0, 0}]
(*    1/2    *)
```

For example, we get the expectation value $E[X]=1/3$:

```
RegionMoment[J, {1, 0}]/RegionMoment[J, {0, 0}]
(*    1/3    *)
```

$E[Y^2]=1/6$:

```
RegionMoment[J, {0, 2}]/RegionMoment[J, {0, 0}]
(*    1/6    *)
```

$E[XY]=1/12$:

```
RegionMoment[J, {1, 1}]/RegionMoment[J, {0, 0}]
(*    1/12    *)
```

Comment: You can use `Triangle` as a region directly.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes in this particular case you can. The method presented here is much more general though. I was trying to answer the general question posed in the title.